# What is the fastest way to check balance of multiple BTC address in python

Tags: blockchain, python

I want to check multiple bitcoin addresses balance in python, can someone suggest a script that can do it fast and without getting api error.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that by fetching an API from a Block Explorer

- [Mempool.space](https://mempool.space/docs/api/rest#get-address-utxo)
- [BlockStream.info](https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora/blob/master/API.md#get-addressaddresstxs)
- [Blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com/api/docs#link_203)

Or by adding a wallet on your Bitcoin node and fetching [listunspent](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listunspent.html)

> without getting api error

Which API are you using?

Comment: Do you have any code that fetch balance from these API's
I am using blockchain API

Answer (score 1):

you can request this API (it's free to use): https://rapidapi.com/juliakafarska/api/bitcoin-api

```
import requests

url = "https://bitcoin-api.p.rapidapi.com/balancesByAddress"

payload = {"addresses": ["16ftSEQ4ctQFDtVZiUBusQUjRrGhM3JYwe", "34xp4vRoCGJym3xR7yCVPFHoCNxv4Twseo"]}
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "YOUR_KEY_HERE",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "bitcoin-api.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

response:

```
{
  "note": "Balances for 2 wallet addresses",
  "count": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 14122055,
      "address": "16ftSEQ4ctQFDtVZiUBusQUjRrGhM3JYwe",
      "btc": 0.00525093
    },
    {
      "id": 25721113,
      "address": "34xp4vRoCGJym3xR7yCVPFHoCNxv4Twseo",
      "btc": 0.00111145
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora/blob/master/API.md

```
import requests

address_list = ["bc1q7cyrfmck2ffu2ud3rn5l5a8yv6f0chkp0zpemf", "1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY", "19SXCX6jvQxzfYfzRRMxjLBkqrNt6BUSJ2"]
for addr in address_list:
    print(requests.get(f"https://blockstream.info/api/address/{addr}").text)
```

**output**

```
{"address":"bc1q7cyrfmck2ffu2ud3rn5l5a8yv6f0chkp0zpemf","chain_stats":{"funded_txo_count":874627,"funded_txo_sum":1002983034753356,"spent_txo_count":874417,"spent_txo_sum":1002858836755824,"tx_count":844034},"mempool_stats":{"funded_txo_count":3,"funded_txo_sum":2604371991,"spent_txo_count":3,"spent_txo_sum":2650678155,"tx_count":3}}
{"address":"1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY","chain_stats":{"funded_txo_count":82575,"funded_txo_sum":535871315837629,"spent_txo_count":82540,"spent_txo_sum":535843538512098,"tx_count":82340},"mempool_stats":{"funded_txo_count":0,"funded_txo_sum":0,"spent_txo_count":0,"spent_txo_sum":0,"tx_count":0}}
{"address":"19SXCX6jvQxzfYfzRRMxjLBkqrNt6BUSJ2","chain_stats":{"funded_txo_count":1,"funded_txo_sum":43915252,"spent_txo_count":0,"spent_txo_sum":0,"tx_count":1},"mempool_stats":{"funded_txo_count":0,"funded_txo_sum":0,"spent_txo_count":0,"spent_txo_sum":0,"tx_count":0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i have script that checks one by one read line by line and tell us, with balance address and also range from 2010 to 2023, you can select range, also you can take output to a file....